# Foreach returns empty when I loop through my database tabel

Tags: php, sql

So I tried to loop through my database tabel with a foreach loop, but when I var_dump the function, it gives me an empty array. Here is the code:

```
   function getComment() {
    $db = connectDB();
    $sql = "SELECT `naam`, `title` FROM `comments` WHERE `naam`=:naam AND `title`=:title";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':naam', $naam);
    $stmt->bindParam(':title', $title);
    $stmt->execute();
    return $stmt->fetchAll();
}

foreach (getComment() as $value) {
    echo $value['naam'];
    echo $value['title'];
}
```

Comment: Because function knows __nothing__ about `$naam` and `$title`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the point of fetching two columns that you already know the value of, but perhaps it's just a cut-down example.

Answer (score 1):

Variables `$naam` and `$title` are **undefined** in function scope. I suppose you want to pass'em as arguments:

```
function getComment($naam, $title) {
    $db = connectDB();
    $sql = "SELECT `naam`, `title` FROM `comments` WHERE `naam`=:naam AND `title`=:title";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':naam', $naam);
    $stmt->bindParam(':title', $title);
    $stmt->execute();
    return $stmt->fetchAll();
}

$naam = 'some naam';
$title = 'some title';
foreach (getComment($naam, $title) as $value) {
    echo $value['naam'];
    echo $value['title'];
}
```

Comment: No, $naam and $title are tabels from the database.

Comment: Make sure you understand what is `table`, `field` and what are you doing in your code.